# Static methods getting slower in when accesses by multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have a situation where my C# application with .Net 4 is accessing a static method within a static class making the method perform slower than when accessed by a single thread. Say for example, If the method is called by a single thread it takes around 1.5 minutes to complete, whereas when called by 2 threads it takes 4 minutes to complete.

Any ideas/suggestion/best practices to increase the performance is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your responses.

Some more info:
This is an application which was using threadpool earlier to perform threading in some parts. I introduced parallel tasks. Hence it's a mix up of TPL and older Thread pool. Say for example one parallel task can have multiple threads. The machine has 24 CPU cores with 64GB RAM. I ran 2 processes which would have split to 5 threads each totalling upto  10 threads. During this the process got slower. I am pasting the code here for those who would like to inspect it and provide suggestions. Sorry for pasting long code. The code may not be having all current latest features as this was coded few years ago. Thanks once again.

```
public static class Property11
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Splits agg rows to separate commands where the reference parameters are included for each command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="worksheetID">The current worksheet ID.</param>
    /// <param name="propertyID">The current property ID.</param>
    /// <param name="ccrFormObj">The ccr form object.</param>
    public static void SplitAggregateIncludeReferenceParameterCCRToDTH(PropertyCall propertyCallObj)
    {
        string worksheetID = propertyCallObj.WorksheetID;
        int propertyID = propertyCallObj.PropertyID;
        IDClass nextIDObj = propertyCallObj.NextIDObj;
        CCRFormStructure ccrFormObj = propertyCallObj.CCRFormObj;
        List<CCRFormStructure> ccrFormObjsToAdd = propertyCallObj.CCRFormObjToAddList;

        DateTime dtProp = DateTime.Now;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Start time property = " + propertyCallObj.PropertyID + ", worksheet = " + propertyCallObj.WorksheetID + ": " + dtProp.ToString());

        try
        {
            // Get all rows for worksheet
            List<WorksheetRow> rowListForWorksheet =
                (from wr in ccrFormObj.myWorksheetRowList
                 where wr.WorksheetID == worksheetID
                 select wr).ToList();

            // Get all parameters for worksheet
            List<WorksheetRowParameter> rowParameterListForWorksheet =
                (from wrp in ccrFormObj.myWorksheetRowParameterList
                 join wr in rowListForWorksheet
                 on wrp.WorksheetRowID equals wr.ID
                 select wrp).ToList();

            // Get all agg rows in worksheet
            List<AggRow> aggRowsInWorksheet =
                (from ar in ccrFormObj.myAggRowList
                 join wsrp in rowParameterListForWorksheet
                 on ar.WorksheetRowParameterID equals wsrp.ID
                 select ar).ToList();

            // Get all agg row parameters in worksheet
            List<AggRowParameter> aggParametersInWorksheet =
                (from arp in ccrFormObj.myAggRowParameterList
                 join ar in aggRowsInWorksheet
                 on arp.AggRowID equals ar.ID
                 select arp).ToList();

            // Get all command mappings for worksheet
            List<CommandMappingObj> commandMappingListForWorksheet =
                (from cm in ccrFormObj.commandMappingList
                 join wr in rowListForWorksheet
                 on cm.WorksheetRowID equals wr.ID
                 select cm).ToList();

            // Get all parameter mappings for worksheet
            List<ParameterMappingObj> parameterMappingListForWorksheet =
                (from pm in ccrFormObj.parameterMappingList
                 join cm in commandMappingListForWorksheet
                 on pm.CommandMappingObjID equals cm.ID
                 select pm).ToList();

            // Get all property objects for  worksheet
            List<ParameterPropertyObj> propertyList =
                (from ppo in ccrFormObj.parameterPropertiesList
                 where ppo.ID == propertyID && ppo.WorksheetID == worksheetID
                 select ppo).ToList();

            //List<WorksheetRow> rowsToRemove = new List<WorksheetRow>();  
            WorksheetRowParameter currentWorksheetRowParameter;
            AggRow currentAggRow;
            AggRowParameter currentAggRowParameter;
            AggRow currentSteeringAggRow;
            AggRowParameter currentSteeringAggRowParameter;
            int newIDIndex = 0;
            List<string> worksheetRowsWithoutTooLongCommandRows = new List<string>();
            WorksheetRow newWSR = new WorksheetRow();
            CommandMappingObj newCMO = new CommandMappingObj();
            WorksheetRow newWSRForOrigRow = new WorksheetRow();
            CommandMappingObj newChangeCMO = new CommandMappingObj();
            List<string> steeringParameters;
            IEnumerable<WorksheetRowParameter> parameterListForRow;
            IEnumerable<WorksheetRowParameter> currentSteeringParameters;
            string newCMOID;
            ParameterMappingObj newPMO;
            WorksheetRowParameter newWSRP;
            string newWSRID;
            string newID;
            IEnumerable<string> commandsWithPropertyParameterForRow;
            Hashtable htPropertyParamAndSteeringParameters = new Hashtable();
            List<string> steeringParametersForProperty;
            WorksheetRowParameter currentWorksheetRowPropertyParameter;
            bool removeOrigRow = false;
            bool firstRowForAggCreated = false;
            List<WorksheetRowParameter> propParamListForFirstCreatedRow = new List<WorksheetRowParameter>();
            List<string> propParamUsedAsSteeringList = new List<string>();

            foreach (ParameterPropertyObj propertyParameter in propertyList)
            {
                if (propertyParameter.SecondaryPropertyInfo != null && propertyParameter.SecondaryPropertyInfo != "")
                {
                    steeringParameters = propertyParameter.SecondaryPropertyInfo.Split(",".ToCharArray()).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    steeringParameters = new List<string>();
                }

                htPropertyParamAndSteeringParameters.Add(propertyParameter.Parameter, steeringParameters);
            }

            var aggListForRow =
                from ar in aggRowsInWorksheet
                join arp in aggParametersInWorksheet
                on ar.ID equals arp.AggRowID
                select new
                {
                    AggRow = ar,
                    AggRowParameter = arp
                };

            var worksheetRowsWithRepParam =
                from wrp in rowParameterListForWorksheet
                where htPropertyParamAndSteeringParameters.Contains(wrp.Parameter)
                join al in aggListForRow
                on wrp.ID equals al.AggRow.WorksheetRowParameterID
                into aggList
                where aggList.Count() > 0
                select new
                {
                    WorksheetRowParameter = wrp,
                    AggList = aggList
                };

            foreach (WorksheetRow worksheetRow in rowListForWorksheet.ToList())
            {
                var worksheetRowWithRepParam =
                    worksheetRowsWithRepParam.Where(wrp => wrp.WorksheetRowParameter.WorksheetRowID == worksheetRow.ID);

                if (worksheetRowWithRepParam.Count() > 0)
                {
                    firstRowForAggCreated = false;

                    var currentMappingList =
                        from cmo in commandMappingListForWorksheet
                        where cmo.WorksheetRowID == worksheetRow.ID
                        join pmo in parameterMappingListForWorksheet
                        on cmo.ID equals pmo.CommandMappingObjID
                        into parameterMappingList
                        select new
                        {
                            CommandMapping = cmo,
                            ParameterMappingList = parameterMappingList
                        };

                    IEnumerable<ParameterPropertyObj> sortedPropertyList =
                        from wrwrp in worksheetRowWithRepParam
                        join ppo in propertyList
                        on wrwrp.WorksheetRowParameter.Parameter equals ppo.Parameter
                        orderby wrwrp.AggList.Count() descending
                        select ppo;

                    propParamUsedAsSteeringList.Clear();

                    foreach (ParameterPropertyObj ppo in sortedPropertyList)
                    {
                        if (!propParamUsedAsSteeringList.Contains(ppo.Parameter))
                        {
                            var currentWorksheetRowsWithRepParam =
                                worksheetRowWithRepParam.Where(p => p.WorksheetRowParameter.Parameter == ppo.Parameter);

                            if (currentWorksheetRowsWithRepParam.Count() == 0)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            var currentWorksheetRowWithRepParam = currentWorksheetRowsWithRepParam.ElementAt(0);

                            var currentAggList = currentWorksheetRowWithRepParam.AggList;

                            if (!firstRowForAggCreated)
                            {
                                currentWorksheetRowPropertyParameter = currentWorksheetRowWithRepParam.WorksheetRowParameter;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                currentWorksheetRowPropertyParameter = propParamListForFirstCreatedRow.Where(p => p.Parameter == ppo.Parameter).ElementAt(0);
                            }

                            if (currentAggList.Count() > 1)
                            {
                                removeOrigRow = true;

                                steeringParametersForProperty = (List<string>)htPropertyParamAndSteeringParameters[ppo.Parameter];

                                currentSteeringParameters =
                                    from wrp in rowParameterListForWorksheet
                                    where wrp.WorksheetRowID == worksheetRow.ID
                                    && steeringParametersForProperty.Contains(wrp.Parameter)
                                    select wrp;

                                commandsWithPropertyParameterForRow =
                                    from cml in currentMappingList
                                    where cml.ParameterMappingList.Count(pmo => pmo.Name == ppo.Parameter) > 0
                                    select cml.CommandMapping.Name;

                                propParamUsedAsSteeringList.AddRange(
                                    from sp in sortedPropertyList
                                    where sp.Parameter != ppo.Parameter
                                    join csp in currentSteeringParameters
                                    on sp.Parameter equals csp.Parameter
                                    select csp.Parameter);

                                // CREATE NEW WORKSHEET ROWS FOR EACH BUT THE FIRST AGG ROW PARAMETER
                                for (int i = 0; i < currentAggList.Count(); i++)
                                {
                                    currentAggRow = currentAggList.ElementAt(i).AggRow;
                                    currentAggRowParameter = currentAggList.ElementAt(i).AggRowParameter;

                                    if (i == 0)
                                    {
                                        currentWorksheetRowPropertyParameter.Value = currentAggRowParameter.Value;

                                        if (!firstRowForAggCreated)
                                        {
                                            propParamListForFirstCreatedRow.Clear();

                                            newWSRID = newIDIndex.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
                                            newID = newWSRID;

                                            if (!worksheetRow.ID.Contains(','))
                                            {
                                                newID = "," + newWSRID;
                                            }

                                            newWSRForOrigRow = new WorksheetRow
                                            {
                                                ID = worksheetRow.ID + newID,
                                                OriginalWorksheetRowID = worksheetRow.OriginalWorksheetRowID,
                                                WorksheetID = worksheetRow.WorksheetID
                                            };

                                            ccrFormObj.myWorksheetRowList.Add(newWSRForOrigRow);

                                            parameterListForRow =
                                                from wrp in rowParameterListForWorksheet
                                                where wrp.WorksheetRowID == worksheetRow.ID
                                                select wrp;

                                            foreach (WorksheetRowParameter currentParameter in parameterListForRow)
                                            {
                                                newID = "";

                                                if ((currentParameter.ID != null) && (!currentParameter.ID.Contains(',')))
                                                {
                                                    newID = ",";
                                                }

                                                newID += newIDIndex.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');

                                                newWSRP = new WorksheetRowParameter
                                                {
                                                    ID = currentParameter.ID + newID,
                                                    OriginalParameterID = currentParameter.OriginalParameterID,
                                                    WorksheetRowID = newWSRForOrigRow.ID,
                                                    Parameter = currentParameter.Parameter,
                                                    Value = currentParameter.Value,
                                                    Disabled = currentParameter.Disabled
                                                };

                                                if (htPropertyParamAndSteeringParameters.Contains(newWSRP.Parameter)
                                                    && newWSRP.Parameter != ppo.Parameter)
                                                {
                                                    // TODO: IF AGG, TAKE AGG POS VALUE

                                                    var steeringParamAggList =
                                                        from wrwrp in worksheetRowWithRepParam
                                                        where wrwrp.WorksheetRowParameter.Parameter == newWSRP.Parameter
                                                        select wrwrp.AggList;

                                                    if (steeringParamAggList.Count() > 0)
                                                    {
                                                        if (steeringParamAggList.ElementAt(0).Count() > i)
                                                        {
                                                            currentSteeringAggRow = steeringParamAggList.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(i).AggRow;
                                                            currentSteeringAggRowParameter = steeringParamAggList.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(i).AggRowParameter;

                                                            newWSRP.Value = currentSteeringAggRowParameter.Value;

                                                            ccrFormObj.myAggRowParameterList.Remove(currentSteeringAggRowParameter);
                                                            ccrFormObj.myAggRowList.Remove(currentSteeringAggRow);

                                                            ccrFormObj.myWorksheetRowParameterList.Add(newWSRP);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        ccrFormObj.myWorksheetRowParameterList.Add(newWSRP);
                                                    }

                                                    propParamListForFirstCreatedRow.Add(newWSRP);
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    ccrFormObj.myWorksheetRowParameterList.Add(newWSRP);
                                                }
                                            }

                                            foreach (var currentMapping in currentMappingList)
                                            {
                                                // Re-point original command mapping to new row
                                                newCMOID = newIDIndex.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');

                                                if (!currentMapping.CommandMapping.ID.Contains(','))
                                                {
                                                    newID = "," + newCMOID;
                                                }

                                                // Create new command mapping object
                                                newCMO = new CommandMappingObj
                                                {
                                                    ID = currentMapping.CommandMapping.ID + newID,
                                                    Name = currentMapping.CommandMapping.Name,
                                                    WorksheetRowID = newWSRForOrigRow.ID
                                                };

                                                ccrFormObj.commandMappingList.Add(newCMO);

                                                foreach (ParameterMappingObj pmo in currentMapping.ParameterMappingList)
                                                {
                                                    newPMO = new ParameterMappingObj
                                                    {
                                                        Name = pmo.Name,
                                                        CommandMappingObjID = newCMO.ID
                                                    };

                                                    ccrFormObj.parameterMappingList.Add(newPMO);
                                                }
                                            }

                                            firstRowForAggCreated = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        newWSRID = newIDIndex.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
                                        newID = newWSRID;

                                        if (!worksheetRow.ID.Contains(','))
                                        {
                                            newID = "," + newWSRID;
                                        }

                                        newWSR = new WorksheetRow
                                        {
                                            ID = worksheetRow.ID + newID,
                                            OriginalWorksheetRowID = worksheetRow.OriginalWorksheetRowID,
                                            WorksheetID = worksheetRow.WorksheetID
                                        };

                                        ccrFormObj.myWorksheetRowList.Add(newWSR);

                                        foreach (WorksheetRowParameter currentSteeringParameter in currentSteeringParameters)
                                        {
                                            newID = "";

                                            if ((currentSteeringParameter.ID != null) && (!currentSteeringParameter.ID.Contains(',')))
                                            {
                                                newID = ",";
                                            }

                                            newID += newIDIndex.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');

                                            newWSRP = new WorksheetRowParameter
                                            {
                                                ID = currentSteeringParameter.ID + newID,
                                                OriginalParameterID = currentSteeringParameter.OriginalParameterID,
                                                WorksheetRowID = newWSR.ID,
                                                Parameter = currentSteeringParameter.Parameter,
                                                Value = currentSteeringParameter.Value,
                                                Disabled = currentSteeringParameter.Disabled
                                            };

                                            var steeringParamAggList =
                                                from wrwrp in worksheetRowWithRepParam
                                                where wrwrp.WorksheetRowParameter.Parameter == newWSRP.Parameter
                                                select wrwrp.AggList;

                                            if (steeringParamAggList.Count() > 0)
                                            {
                                                if (steeringParamAggList.ElementAt(0).Count() > i)
                                                {
                                                    currentSteeringAggRow = steeringParamAggList.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(i).AggRow;
                                                    currentSteeringAggRowParameter = steeringParamAggList.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(i).AggRowParameter;

                                                    newWSRP.Value = currentSteeringAggRowParameter.Value;

                                                    ccrFormObj.myAggRowParameterList.Remove(currentSteeringAggRowParameter);
                                                    ccrFormObj.myAggRowList.Remove(currentSteeringAggRow);

                                                    ccrFormObj.myWorksheetRowParameterList.Add(newWSRP);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                ccrFormObj.myWorksheetRowParameterList.Add(newWSRP);
                                            }
                                        }

                                        // Add rep param
                                        newID = "";

                                        if ((currentWorksheetRowPropertyParameter.ID != null) && (!currentWorksheetRowPropertyParameter.ID.Contains(',')))
                                        {
                                            newID = ",";
                                        }

                                        newID += newIDIndex.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');

                                        newWSRP = new WorksheetRowParameter
                                        {
                                            ID = currentWorksheetRowPropertyParameter.ID + newID,
                                            OriginalParameterID = currentWorksheetRowPropertyParameter.OriginalParameterID,
                                            WorksheetRowID = newWSR.ID,
                                            Parameter = currentWorksheetRowPropertyParameter.Parameter,
                                            Value = currentAggRowParameter.Value,
                                            Disabled = currentWorksheetRowPropertyParameter.Disabled
                                        };

                                        ccrFormObj.myWorksheetRowParameterList.Add(newWSRP);

                                        foreach (var currentMapping in currentMappingList)
                                        {
                                            if (commandsWithPropertyParameterForRow.Contains(currentMapping.CommandMapping.Name))
                                            {
                                                newCMOID = newIDIndex.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');

                                                if (!currentMapping.CommandMapping.ID.Contains(','))
                                                {
                                                    newID = "," + newCMOID;
                                                }

                                                // Create new command mapping object
                                                newCMO = new CommandMappingObj
                                                {
                                                    ID = currentMapping.CommandMapping.ID + newID,
                                                    Name = currentMapping.CommandMapping.Name,
                                                    WorksheetRowID = newWSR.ID
                                                };

                                                ccrFormObj.commandMappingList.Add(newCMO);

                                                foreach (ParameterMappingObj pmo in currentMapping.ParameterMappingList)
                                                {
                                                    if ((pmo.Name == ppo.Parameter) || (currentSteeringParameters.Count(p => p.Parameter == pmo.Name) > 0))
                                                    {
                                                        newPMO = new ParameterMappingObj
                                                        {
                                                            Name = pmo.Name,
                                                            CommandMappingObjID = newCMO.ID
                                                        };

                                                        ccrFormObj.parameterMappingList.Add(newPMO);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    newIDIndex++;

                                    ccrFormObj.myAggRowParameterList.Remove(currentAggRowParameter);
                                    ccrFormObj.myAggRowList.Remove(currentAggRow);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                currentAggRow = currentAggList.ElementAt(0).AggRow;
                                currentAggRowParameter = currentAggList.ElementAt(0).AggRowParameter;
                                currentWorks
```

Comment: It is not possible to answer without specifics about what your code does. *Anything* could be the cause.

Comment: There is no way to tell without looking at your method. Possible answers range from poor coding to cache alignment issues.

Comment: isnt the method being crossed? since its static there is only 1 implementation so all the threads would use the same 1? - i am realy asking

Comment: Does that method have `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`? If not, then I'm pretty sure the problem is not in the method itself, but something in its code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing *intrinsic* about a static method that would make it slower when accessed by multiple threads, unless for example:

- you have some shared resource that is being a throttle, such as a shared `lock`, or going to a single UI thread
- you have more threads than available CPU cores, and it is simply having to do lots of switching
- you are maxing out some other resource, such as disk IO, network IO, etc

Since you haven't posted any code, we can only guess.